# Reset a vector to initial state in for loop

Tags: python, numpy

Assume I have a vector `v=np.zeros(1000)`

and I have  the following for-loop

```py
y = dict{}

for x in training_set:
   v[idx>100]=1
   y[idx]=v
   v=v*0
```

I can think of several ways of "resetting" `v` to its initial-state (being pure zeros), which is the problem (the example above is just to clarify what I mean with resetting the vector)

```py
v=v*0 (1)
v=np.zeros(1000) (2)

V=np.zeros(1000) (3)
v=V
```

Either multiply it by 0, create it from new, or have a variable being pure zeros, which I then copy to `v`.

What would be the fastest way (or is there a way which is even faster)?

Comment: You can benchmark all those options yourself. See [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Comment: are you repeatedly setting `v[idx>100]=1`? or is there something else hapening to `v` in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, but `idx` is changed in each loop

Comment: What’s `training_set`? The loop might be unnecessary.